# Combining content of mutliple cells into 1 cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 300 names written in A1,B1,C1,D1 and so on...
I want them in one cell, each name separated by comma.

I have tried a lot to automate the concatenate function `&` ,but in vain.Seems dragging cells and such stuff would not work.

Any tips?Thanks

Comment: You can use concatenate and type in all the cells, also the & sign works to. A1&","&B1 ... etc. If your row count changes dynamically you probably want to look at a look in VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tiny macro:

```
Sub KonKat()
    stt = Cells(1, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To 300
        stt = stt & ", " & Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i
    Cells(2, 1).Value = stt
End Sub
```

The result will be placed in cell **A2**

Comment: the result i get in A2 is what is in cell A1 followed by hundreds of commas...hmm